# How to Provide Breadcrumbs for Page with dynamic Parameters?

Tags: html, grails, groovy, breadcrumbs

I found a Grails framework for generating Breadcrumbs [here](https://adityakalia.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/breadcrumbs-framework-for-grails/). It does generate breadcrumbs based on a static definition in a breadcrumbs.xml file where it defines the hierarchies of the crumbs:

```
     <map>
        <nav id="homeCrumb" matchController="samplePages" matchAction="homeBreadCrumbPage">
            <!-- levels navigation -->
            <nav id="itemsLevel1Crumb" matchController="samplePages" matchAction="level1BreadCrumbPage">
                <nav id="itemsLevel2Crumb" matchController="samplePages" matchAction="level2BreadCrumbPage">
                    <nav id="itemsLevel3Crumb" matchController="samplePages" matchAction="level3BreadCrumbPage">
                        <nav id="showItemCrumb" matchController="samplePages" matchAction="itemDetailsBreadCrumbPage"/>
                    </nav>
                </nav>
            </nav>
            <nav id="simple1Crumb" matchController="samplePages" matchAction="simpleBreadCrumb"/>
            <nav id="simple2Crumb" matchController="samplePages" matchAction="simpleBreadCrumbWithAttr"/>
            <!-- levels navigation -->
        </nav>
    </map>
```

This file is evaluated and printed by a taglib:

```
class BreadCrumbTagLib {

    static def log = LogFactory.getLog("grails.app.breadCrumbTag")

    def breadCrumb = { attrs , body ->

            def manager = BreadCrumbManager.getInstance()
            def uri = request.getRequestURI() 
            def context = request.getContextPath() 

            def controller = params.controller
            def action = params.action

            def attrTitle =  attrs.title
            def attrLink = attrs.link

            // if controller and action are missing from params try to get them from request url
            if (!controller && !action && uri && context && uri.indexOf(context) != -1) {
                def uriParams = uri.substring(uri.indexOf(context) + (context.length() + 1), uri.length())
                def uriArray = uriParams.split('/')

                if (uriArray.size() >= 2 ) {
                    controller = uriArray[0]
                    action = uriArray[1]                       
                }
            }

            def crumbs = manager.getBreadCrumbs(controller, action)

            if (crumbs) {
                out << '<div class="breadcrumb"><ul>'
                def size = crumbs.size()
                crumbs.eachWithIndex { crumb, index ->
                    out << '<li>'

                    // override title and link of breadcrumb on current page (i.e. last bread crumb in hierarchy)
                    // if name, link attributes are supplied
                    if (index == size - 1) {
                        if (attrTitle)
                            crumb.title = attrTitle
                        if (attrLink)
                            crumb.link = attrLink
                    }
                    // set title to undefined if not found, associated 
                    // renderer if present can overwrite it
                    if (!crumb.title)
                        crumb.title = "undefined"
                    if (crumb.title && crumb.title.size() > 40)
                        crumb.title = crumb.title.substring(0, 40) + "..."

                    if (crumb.viewController && crumb.viewAction) {
                        def content = g.include(controller:crumb.viewController, action:crumb.viewAction, breadcrumb:crumb, params:params)
                        out << content
                    } else if (crumb.viewTemplate) {
                        def content = g.include(view:crumb.viewTemplate, breadcrumb:crumb, params: params)
                        out << content
                    } else if (crumb.linkToController && crumb.linkToAction && (size - 1 > index)){
                        out << "<a href=\"${g.createLink (controller: crumb.linkToController, action: crumb.linkToAction)}\">${crumb.title}</a>"
                    // if crumb has a link and its not the last vread crumb then show link else
                    // just show the text
                    } else if (crumb.link && (size - 1 > index)){
                        out << "<a href=\"${crumb.link}\">${crumb.title}</a>"
                    } else {
                        out << "${crumb.title}"
                    }
                    out << "</li>"
                    // do not print for last bread crumb
                    if (size - 1 > index)
                        out << "<li>&raquo;</li>"
                }
                out << "</ul></div>"
            }
    }
}
```

Problem: When I have a structure where I need some params which are not fix.

Example: I am in the third level of navigation lets say

```
A1 / A2 / A3
```

In my case `A2` should open a page like `user/show/1234` where 1234 is the id of the user to show. The problem is that I cannot add 1234 hard coded in the breadcrumbs.xml file because this id changes depending on which user you want to show.

**How can I handle this when an intermediate breadcrumbs link needs dynamic parameters?**

Comment: The plugin isn't designed for that use case. It's designed for static mapping of breadcrumbs. You will need to fork the plugin and make it have this feature, or use another means for creating your breadcrumbs.

Comment: Could you please sketch how to do it?

Comment: Well, you're going to need to provide a new attribute for the tag, this would be the instance you want to use to get the value from (e.g. the id value for instance) then come up with some new attribute in the configuration xml that you can store a pattern in that you will evaluate in the tag library to add in the parameters to the URL of the href that is being generated. I'd suggest you look at the source code for a few of the built in Grails tags and see if you can get any ideas on how to do that from there (in particular the link tag).

Comment: Could you please provide it in an answer a bit more detailed. Al least where to set the parameter the breadcrumbs are fetching?

Comment: The problem with your idea is that you can do this only for the last tag in the breadcrumbs. But, you need the tag attributes for the tag which you have visited before. To generate links. You do no need a link for the current breadcrum. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Without knowing your exact domain model and how you intend on deriving this it's hard to say. I was under the assumption that A1, A2, and A3 were related in some way. Thus given an A3 it would have a property that pointed to the relevant A2 which in turn would have a property that pointed to the relevant A1 (if needed). Without knowing all the details on how you are trying to use the breadcrumbs it's hard to give you any specifics. Your question is far too general to solicit an "example" answer.

Comment: No they are not related. It is like a1 is company/show/1235342, a2 is user/showall/1234 and c2 is like user/show/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it some more, I realized it may be better not to use the HttpSession. If you use a session-scoped service instead it will be easier to unit test the breadcrumb code.

First, create a session-scoped service to maintain the user's navigation history.

```
class NavigationHistoryService {
    static transactional = false
    static scope = "session"

    def history = [:]

    public List push(String controller, String action, Map params) {
        def crumb = [
            action: action, 
            params: params]

        history.controller = crumb

        return history
    }
```

In your controllers inject the service and use it to keep track of where the user has been. Then add the history as part of what's returned by the action's model:

```
class CompanyController {
    def navigationHistoryService

    def show() {
        navigationHistoryService.push('company', 'show', params)
        ...
        [crumbs: navigationHistoryService.history] 
    }
}
```

Finally, use the history in your GSP to render the crumbs.

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><g:link controller="company" action="${crumbs.company.action}" params="${crumbs.company.params}">SOMETHING</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I liked the way it is done in this post: https://adityakalia.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/breadcrumbs-framework-for-grails/ with the xml file. The XML files defines the hierarchies of the crumbs. Do you see how this could be integrated in your approach or do you see a way to update the other approach?

Comment: Is the hierarchy something like this: (company/show/ID) / (user/showall/ID) / (user/show/ID)? In other words, does each level retain the controller and action and only the ID changes?

Comment: Yes you got it. There might be other parameters too beside the id but basically that's it. Any idea on that?

Comment: I changed it to keep each level fixed. Instead of working like a history stack it keeps track of the last action and params per controller.

Comment: I still do not see how this integrates with the existing code I had from the link I showed. I make you an offer. I make a bounty out of this post of 50Reps. You make a detailed description of how I have to change and extend the existing code from here: https://adityakalia.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/breadcrumbs-framework-for-grails/ Does this sounds fair to you?

Comment: Make that 500 Reps and I'll also modify the code into a proper Grails plugin and host it on bitbucket. Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: You don't have to make the plugin. I still have to code running. The only thing I need is what to modify. So 50Reps?

Comment: No thanks. That amount of effort is worth more to me.

Comment: How would you help me for 50Reps?

Comment: I'd love to help. But the bounty needs to be far more attractive.

Comment: How do you inject a Service with session scope? I get an error when I do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your breadcrumbs are in the format CONTROLLER/ACTION/ID. If that's so, the information you need is already available in your GSP via the webRequest property. Here's an example using Twitter Bootstrap breadcrumbs:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">${webRequest.controllerName}</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">${webRequest.actionName}</a></li>
  <li class="active">${webRequest.id}</li>
</ol>
```

You'd still have to set up the hrefs to something meaningful. A more robust approach would be something like this...

```
<g:set var="crumbs" value="${[webRequest.controllerName, webRequest.actionName, webRequest.id].findAll { it != null }}.collect { [label: it, active: false] }" />
<% crumbs.last().active = true %>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <g:each in="${crumbs}">
        <li class="${it.active ? 'active' : ''}"><a href="#">${it.label}</a></li>
    </g:each>
</ol>
```

Embedding Groovy code into GSP via the <% %> tags is not recommended, but something like this could be done in a TagLib. This approach can handle breadcrumbs of 1-3 parts in length. It adjusts according to the current URI.

Comment: Yes, but this approach only works for the current request. My problem is how to set the link to the breadcrumb of the previous page. This might not work this way? What do you think?

Comment: Oooooh. _Now_ I see what you're trying to do. You can use the HttpSession in your controller action methods to maintain a breadcrumb history. For example: `session.crumbs.add(WHATEVER)` And then you can loop through the `session.crumbs` in your GSP to render the crumbs.

Comment: Could you please update your answer and explain this a little bit more detailed please? The problem is that the current url has no indication of what was in the last even if they should be in a hierarchy. The problem is that when you go to A -> B -> A you do not want to add A twice. Look forward to your response. Thanks!

Comment: Since the approach is quite different I'll create a new answer. My blunder can stay right here for eternity.

Comment: Yes you can do that. I am looking forward to it. Give you still an upvote for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
use simple by blade view
 <ul class="breadcrumb" style="padding-right: 20px">
                <li> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <a class="active" href="{{url('/')}}">Home</a>
                    {{--<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>--}}
                </li> <?php $link = url('/') ; ?>
                @for($i = 1; $i <= count(Request::segments()); $i++)
                    <li>
                        @if($i < count(Request::segments()) & $i > 0)
                            <?php $link .= "/" . Request::segment($i); ?>
                                <a class="active" href="<?= $link ?>">{{Request::segment($i)}}</a>
                                {{--{!!'<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'!!}--}}
                        @else {{Request::segment($i)}}
                        @endif
                    </li>
                @endfor
            </ul>
```